# Why PropertyDescriptor and Reflection don't work equally in 1.7 as in 1.6 with generics?

Tags: java, generics, java-7

Recently I faced a strange behaviour in one application I maintain. Sources are compiled with version 1.6_33, but run under 1.7u21. The client decided to change the version without consulting and I have no influence on their choice.

In the architecture, some interfaces are parameterized under certain conditions to restrict their usage. The parameterized concrete class must use one of the concrete parameter defined. For convenience, PropertyDescritor was used by a mecanism responsible to instantiate a ConcreteParameter (for additional processes). This behaviour worked well with version 6 but no more with version 7.

With version 7, when trying to fetch the class of the parameter, the returning type is always of type **Parameter** whereas in version 6 the type is **ConcreteParameter**. One exception occur in java and is presented in the example below. But why would that work in this case ?!

I browsed [JLS 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) and also [java 7 compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html) without finding any explanation of this behaviour. To me this is illogical not having the concrete type. Can someone explain me why is this happening ? Isn't it a bug, that reflection works with getDeclaredMethod(...) but not with getDeclaredMethods() ?

Thanks in advance.

The following example illustrates what worked by the past :

```
package fr.free.naoj;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.junit.Test;

public class PropertyDescriptorAndReflectionTest {

    @Test public void testPropertyDescriptorInnerWithJava7() {
        PropertyDescriptor pd;
        try {
            // Fails
            pd = new PropertyDescriptor("parameter", ConcreteClass.class);
            assertEquals(ConcreteParameter.class, pd.getPropertyType());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }
    }

    @Test public void testReflectionOnGenericClassWithJava7() {
        try {
            // Works
            Method m = ConcreteClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("getParameter", new Class<?>[]{});
            m.setAccessible(true);
            assertEquals(ConcreteParameter.class, m.getReturnType());

            // Fails
            for (Method me : ConcreteClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                me.setAccessible(true);
                if (me.getName().equals("getParameter")) {
                    assertEquals(ConcreteParameter.class, me.getReturnType());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }
    }

    private class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass<ConcreteParameter> {
        @Override public ConcreteParameter getParameter() {
            this.parameter = new ConcreteParameter();
            return this.parameter;
        }

        @Override public void setParameter(ConcreteParameter parameter) {
            this.parameter = parameter;
        }
    }

    private abstract class AbstractClass<P extends Parameter> implements Super<P> {
        protected P parameter; 
    }

    private interface Super<P extends Parameter> {
        P getParameter();

        void setParameter(P parameter);
    }

    private class ConcreteParameter implements Parameter {
        @Override public String sayHello() {
            return "hello";
        }
    }

    private interface Parameter {
        String sayHello();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the end.

`ConcreteClass.getDeclaredMethods()` gives 4 results under Java 6 and Java 7, not just 2: `getParameter()` returning `ConcreteParameter`, and `setParameter(ConcreteParameter)`; but also `getParameter()` returning `Parameter`, and `setParameter(Parameter)`. The only thing that differs here between Java 6 and Java 7 is the order in which the methods are returned from `getDeclaredMethods`. I think that's mentioned in the Java 7 compatibility document you referenced.

The extra methods correspond to the bridge methods added by the compiler to make generics work with erasure, i.e. the compiler will generate two hidden methods like this in class `ConcreteClass`:

```
public void setParameter(Parameter p) {
    setParameter((ConcreteParameter) p);
}

public Parameter getParameter() {
    return getParameter(); // calls the 'real' one!
}
```

(This isn't legal Java code since you are not allowed to have two methods which only differ by their return type, but in byte code it's fine since the return type is part of the signature of the method for the JVM.)

If you read the JavaDoc for `Class#getDeclaredMethod` we see this:

> If more than one method with the same parameter types is declared in a class, and one of these methods has a return type that is more specific than any of the others, that method is returned; otherwise one of the methods is chosen arbitrarily.

So the behaviour you are seeing for `getDeclaredMethod` and `getDeclaredMethods` seems to be in the spec, the most specific method is returned for `getDeclaredMethod` and multiple methods are returned for `getDeclaredMethods`.

However, it seems the behaviour you are seeing with the `PropertyDescriptor` is a recurrence of [bug 6788525](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6788525). Probably it is just taking the first method that it finds with the name that it wants, which means it gets it wrong sometimes. I suggest you lodge a bug report with Oracle.

Comment: Thanks rxg for your review and answer. Indeed the behaviour for getDeclaredMethod and getDeclaredMethods seems logical.

And I'm also going to report this to Oracle.